# How can I re-use a sqlalchemy ORM model on multiple databases and schemas?

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I have a SQLAlchemy ORM model that currently looks a bit like this:

```
Base = declarative_base()

class Database(Base):

  __tablename__ = "databases"
  __table_args__ = (
    saschema.PrimaryKeyConstraint('db', 'role'),
    {
      'schema' : 'defines',
      },
    )


  db = Column(String, nullable=False)
  role = Column(String, nullable=False)
  server = Column(String)
```

Here's the thing, in practice this model exists in multiple databases, and in those databases it'll exist in mutiple schemas.  For any one operation I'll only use one `(database, schema)` tuple.

Right now, I can set the database engine using this:

```
Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker())
Session.configure(bind=my_db_engine)
# ... do my operations on the model here.
```

But I'm not sure how I can change the `__table_args__` at execution time so that the schema will be the right one.

Comment: Do you know the database and schema that you need before you have done any queries?

Comment: No; the name of the DB and the schema are fields in another model from yet another DB. I find those first, and then I want to associate an instance of this model to that connection.

Comment: Have you found a viable solution to this?  I also have one database with many schemas, each with the same set of tables that I would love to be able to set the schema either at query time or else at the session level.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use the create_engine to bind the models to a schema/database rather than do so in the actual database.

```
#first connect to the database that holds the DB and schema
engine1 = create_engine('mysql://user:pass@db.com/schema1')

Session = session(sessionmaker())
session = Session(bind=engine1)

#fetch the first database
database = session.query(Database).first()

engine2 = create_engine('mysql://user:pass@%s/%s' % (database.DB, database.schema))
session2 = Session(bind=engine2)
```

I don't know that this is ideal, but it is one way to do it. If you cache the list of databases before hand then in most cases you are only having to create one session.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also looking for an elegant solution for this problem.  If there are standard tables/models, but different table names, databases, and schemas at runtime, how is this handled?  Others have suggested writing some sort of function that takes a tablename and schema argument, and constructs the model for you.  I've found that using `__abstract__` helps.  I've suggested a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20787457/using-a-different-schema-for-the-same-declarative-base-in-sqlalchemy/20817288#20817288) that may be useful.  It involves adding a Base with a specific schema/metadata into the inheritance.