# Using a different schema for the same declarative Base in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, schema, pyramid

I am new to both Pyramid and SQLAlchemy.  I am working on a Python Pyramid project with SQLAlchemy.  I have a simple model set up below.  How would I go about being able to use this with different schemas at run-time?  This will be a PostgreSQL database backend.  Right now, "public" is hard-coded into the declarative base model.  I would need the ability to use this same model with different schema.  What is the best approach?  Unless I missed it, the documentation at SQLAlchemy seemed unclear to me.

```
    from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
    from sqlalchemy import Column, BigInteger

    __all__ = [
        "LoadTender"
    ]
    __all__.sort()

    Base = declarative_base()


    class LoadTender(Base):
        __tablename__ = "load_tenders"
        __table_args__ = {"schema": "public"}

        id = Column("pkey", BigInteger, primary_key=True)

        def __repr__(self):
            return "" % self.id
```

EDIT: I have appeared to solve my issue, I am updating the snippet to show what I did below.

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, BigInteger

__all__ = [
    "LoadTender"
]
__all__.sort()

Base = declarative_base()

class ClientMixin(object):
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "client_schema_name"}


class LoadTenderMixin(object):
    __tablename__ = "load_tenders"

    id = Column("pkey", BigInteger, primary_key=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "" % self.id


class ClientLoadTender(LoadTenderMixin, ClientMixin, Base):
    pass
```

Comment: I believe I may have solved this by using Declarative Base and using multiple inherited Mixins.  I'll update when I'm certain I have this working ...

Comment: This looks like a great answer, but it may become a problem if any classes earlier in the hierarchy also have a `__table_args__`, as this property will get overwritten.  For example, `ClientLoadTender` may define `PrimaryKeyConstraint`s or `UniqueConstraint`s in `__table_args__`.  I've not found a simple way to merge `__table_args__` down the hierarchy.

Comment: Yes you are correct.  That is a limitation of this arrangement.  However it fit my needs for the application I was applying it to.  I would imagine one would have to write some kind of helper method on the final class in the chain to merge those in manually...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think you need a different model for each schema. `__abstract__` can make this less painful.  This follows on to Paul Yin's answer...

1. Define an `__abstract__` LoadTender model, so you don't have to keep coding it.

   ```
   #base.py
   class LoadTender(Base):
       __abstract__ = True
       id = ...
       def __repr__ ...
   ```
2. Put a schema-specific Base in the hierarchy for each schema.

   ```
   #schema1.py
   from base import LoadTender

   PublicBase = declarative_base(metadata=MetaData(schema='public'))

   class LoadTender(PublicBase, LoadTender):
       __tablename__ = 'load_tenders'
   ```
3. Do the same for other schema.

Comment: This seems to be the closest answer the answered what I was trying to accomplish.  I actually accomplished it by using multiple inheritance just like this with Mixin classes.

Comment: As I'm trying to find a better answer myself, would you mind posting your solution?

Comment: I used Python's multiple inheritance to mix-in the properties I needed for each schema.  The `ClientMixin` could probably have had an `__init__` call to set it to a dynamic setting at run-time, but defining each client as a separate, empty class in my business case was OK.

Comment: Can you bind an engine in Base and declare metadata for schema in PublicBase?

Answer (score 2):

Just another method that didn't seem to have been mentioned often as it deserved:

```
engine.update_execution_options(schema_translate_map={None: "target_schema"})
```

Comment: I find this really a brilliant solution, that avoided to me a lot of code refactoring.
In my case, I just wanted to have a test schema, to use for testing routines in a Postgres environment.
With just one line of code, this solves my problem.
I guess the other approaches I saw are maybe more powerful or flexible, but they would have needed much more modifications in my case, and to different Python modules.
This way, I only had to add this line once, within the constructor of the Class I use as a DB interactor

Answer (score 0):

You can have a base module in package model

```
app\
    models\
        base.py
        schema1.py
        schema2.py
    views\
    ...
```

declare `Base` in base.py, then import it to other schemas

Answer (score -1):

just a guess

```
LoadTender.__table_args__["schema"] = "whatever"
```

Probably best to put it somewhere where your app configurator is creating the app

Comment: nope, that won't work, because `__table_args__ seem to be passed on once upon class definition and do not propagate later on. `LoadTender.__table__.schema = "whatever"` works but is not nice either.