# Can sqlalchemy support using different schema at same time?

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, schema

By default the SQLAlchemy use public schema for Base. below is some code

```
        self.Base = automap.automap_base()
        self.Base.prepare(self.engine, reflect=True)
        Session = sessionmaker(bind = self.engine)
        self.session = Session()
        insp = reflection.Inspector.from_engine(self.engine)
        print(insp.get_table_names())
```

but this code lists me the tables of only public schema like this

```
['drs', 'spatial_ref_sys', 'users']
```

I want to handle all the tables from different schema. and not just the one in public. Any good way to get this done without much hassle ?

**UPDATE 1 :**
Here is similar example with similar problem but with declarative case

[Using a different schema for the same declarative Base in sqlalchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20787457/using-a-different-schema-for-the-same-declarative-base-in-sqlalchemy)

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue. In my case, I simply didn't set the primary key for the second schema. Since `auto_map` cannot map the tables without a primary key, it didn't show me the table from the second schema.